# ng-grid not showing grid in ie 8

Tags: c#, angularjs, internet-explorer-8, ng-grid

I am trying to display some data using ng-grid in a project for a client,
all is well except in IE8 (both emulated mode from IE11 and VM on win 7 through browserstack), here the grid doesn't get rendered (only the container-div that is to hold the columns and rows is rendered) and the exceptions I get in the console are:

"Unable to get property 'width' of undefined or null reference"

"Unable to get property 'scrollTop' of undefined or null reference"

Using ng-grid (version 2.0.7) with angular (version 1.2.3) on a .net based project. (jQuery version used in the project is 1.11.)

Since the console in IE doesn't really give me more info on traces than that, I figured I'd ask the wonderful ppl here at stackoverflow if someone is facing a similar issue or anyone has a clue to where to look.

Peace and thanks in advance for taking the time!

Code for front-end (added)
Here is part of the code on the front-end

```
<div data-ng-controller="benefitsController" >
    <div id="topOrderBox-list" class="topOrderBox">

        <div class="left">
            <div class="boxHeader">
                Sök tjänst
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label class="">
                        <b>Frisökning</b></label>
                    <span class="help" title="Fritextsökning: Här kan du anger olika saker ">[?]</span> </li>
                <li>
                    <input class="freeSearch search" type="text" placeholder="Skriv ett sökord" ng-model="model.filterText" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <b>Leverantörer</b></label>
                    <span class="help" title="Leverantörer: Här kan du söka efter en viss leverantör">[?]</span> </li>
                <li>
                    <select class="partnersOption" ng-model="model.Partner" ng-options="partner.PartnerName for partner in model.Partners | orderBy:'PartnerName'">
                        <option value="">Välj en leverantör</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <b>Välj en typ av förmån</b></label>
                    <span class="help" title="Typ av förmån: Här kan du söka på olika typer av förmåner. ">[?]</span> </li>
                <li>
                    <select class="subCategoryOption" data-ng-model="model.SubCategory" data-ng-options="subCategory.SubCategoryName for subCategory in model.SubCategories | orderBy:'SubCategoryName'">
                        <option value="">Välj en typ av förmån</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div data-ng-grid="gridOptions" class="gridStyle"></div>
        </div>


        <div data-ng-if="!(selectedRow[0].IsOrderable)" class="benefitDetails overflow" data-ng-show="selectedRow.length > 0">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img id="partnerImageId" class="partnerImg" data-ng-src="@Url.Action("Show", "Image")/{{selectedRow[0].PartnerImageId}}" alt="Saknar tjänst bild"/>
                    <img id="benefitImageId" class="benefitImg" data-ng-src="@Url.Action("Show", "Image")/{{selectedRow[0].ImageId}}" alt="Saknar tjänst bild"/>

                    <h2>{{selectedRow[0].PartnerName}} {{selectedRow[0].BenefitName}} {{selectedRow[0].TimeSpanString}}, {{selectedRow[0].City}}</h2>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>


    </div>

    <div class="benefitDetails overflow padding-top" ng-show="selectedRow.length > 0">


            <div class="spanDiv">
                <span ng-bind-html="selectedRow[0].CommonDescription"></span>
                <br />
                <br />
                <span class="taxDescription" ng-bind-html="selectedRow[0].TaxDescription"></span>
            </div>

        </div>

    <div class="bottomLinksBox">
        <a data-ng-controller="sendOrderBenefitController" data-ng-click="goToTop()" class="up" href="#">Upp &uarr;</a>

            <a data-ng-if="selectedRow[0].IsOrderable" class="buttonLink rightBox" id="goOnLink" ng-href="@Url.Action("OtherBenefitsOrdering")/{{selectedRow[0].EmployerBenefitId}}" >Gå vidare till beställning</a>

    </div>
    <div class="contractBox">
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is some of the code on in the controller

```
adderasApp.controller('benefitsController', ['$scope', 'benefitsService', function ($scope, benefitsService) {

    $scope.model = benefitsService.Benefits.get({ isHealthCare: 'false' }, function () {
        $scope.EmployerBenefits = $scope.model.EmployerBenefits;
    });

    $scope.selectedRow = [];

    $scope.filterOptions = {
        filterText: ''
    };



    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'EmployerBenefits',
        columnDefs: [
            { field: 'PartnerName', displayName: 'Leverantör' },
            { field: 'City', displayName: 'Ort' },
            { field: 'BenefitName', displayName: 'Tjänst' },
            { field: 'SubCategoryName', displayName: 'Kategori' },
            { field: 'PriceString', displayName: 'Pris' },
            { field: 'TimeSpanString', displayName: 'Tid' },
        ],
        multiSelect: false,
        selectedItems: $scope.selectedRow,
        filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
        headerClass: 'otherBenefitSearchHeader'
        //headerRowTemplate: '<div ng-style="{\'z-index\': col.zIndex()}" ng-class="{\'col_select\': col.showSortButtonDown(), \'col_select_up\': col.showSortButtonUp() }" ng-repeat="col in visibleColumns()" class="ngHeaderCell col{{$index}}" ng-header-cell></div>'
    };

    $scope.$watch('[ model.Partner, model.SubCategory, model.filterText, model.CommonDescription]', function (newValue, oldValue) {


        var searchText = [];
        var isOrderable;

        if (newValue[0] !== undefined && newValue[0] != null) {
            searchText.push(newValue[0].PartnerName);
        }
        if (newValue[1] !== undefined && newValue[1] != null) {
            searchText.push(newValue[1].SubCategoryName);
        }
        if (newValue[2] !== undefined && newValue[2] != null) {
            searchText.push(newValue[2]);
        }

        if (newValue[3] !== undefined && newValue[3] != null) {
            searchText.push(newValue[3].CommonDescription);
        }

        $scope.filterOptions.filterText = searchText.join(';');



    }, true);

}]);
```

Have tried following the http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie aswell.

P.s. the data from the factories/services are fetching data from the same domain and the data seems to get through, other pages which not use ng-grid but restful services seems to be working fine.

Anyways, thanks again for putting in the time and effort for this!
Peace

Comment: it would be helpfull to share the code...

Comment: Thanks @KristofFeys, now the front-end code and the controller code have been added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution! :)
Basically its IE8 that is very picky about reading js and ,.
I solved it after reading this https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/543
So in my controller code for the ng-grid I removed the , after the last parameter in the gridOptions columnDefs object. Such as:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'EmployerBenefits',
    columnDefs: [
        { field: 'PartnerName', displayName: 'Leverantör' },
        { field: 'City', displayName: 'Ort' },
        { field: 'BenefitName', displayName: 'Tjänst' },
        { field: 'SubCategoryName', displayName: 'Kategori' },
        { field: 'PriceString', displayName: 'Pris' },
        { field: 'TimeSpanString', displayName: 'Tid' }
    ],
    multiSelect: false,
    selectedItems: $scope.selectedRow,
    filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
    headerClass: 'otherBenefitSearchHeader'
    //headerRowTemplate: '<div ng-style="{\'z-index\': col.zIndex()}" ng-class="{\'col_select\': col.showSortButtonDown(), \'col_select_up\': col.showSortButtonUp() }" ng-repeat="col in visibleColumns()" class="ngHeaderCell col{{$index}}" ng-header-cell></div>'
};
```

Anyways peace and thanks for the input guys! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Angular has issues with IE prior to 10. Follow [this guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie) to get it to work. That said, Angular and IE8 have some [very difficult issues to get around](http://blog-it.hypoport.de/2013/08/24/how-to-make-your-angularjs-app-work-in-ie-8/).

For my apps, I have had to add shims for HTML5 support, Modernizr, full jQuery, and shims for the HTML5 controls.  Just to support IE9 and back. And it is spotty at best.

Comment: Thanks for your time and comment, I agree IE8 seems to make it a bit difficult. Will read a bit more about shims etc to see if that may help in this situation.

Comment: Thanks for the input, will look at shims for other purposes aswell. Will anyway need modernizer for basic css manipulation and other stuff as well.. sigh. Peace :)